# How to Implement a javascript solution to calculate the total length of iron bars required to create a gate?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, calculation

Please help me to solve this problem,

Implement a javascript app that can calculate the total length of iron bars required to create a gate
. The gate will have an alternating design of empty rows and rows filled with circles (please note the design starts with an empty row from top). Design should be symmetrical. If a symmetrical design cannot be generated for given inputs, the programme should identify and show a message to the user.

Note:

Bar will have a thickness of 10cm;
Take this value into account when doing calculations.
Minimise the waste of bars as much as possible.

Inputs:

width and height of gate (in cm)
Max height percentage of each row (ex. If the gate height is 100cm and the max row height is 10%, then each row can be a max 10cm in height).

[image: please see this image]

This is the code block.

```
function calculateTotalBarLengthReq(gateWidth, gateHeight, rowHeightPercentage, barThickness) {
  return false;
}

const ironBarThickness = 10;
calculateTotalBarLengthReq(500, 500, 20, ironBarThickness);
```

The answer should be 7021.59cm.

I tried to calculate the total length of iron bars required to create a gate.

Comment: "*I tried to calculate the total length of iron bars required to create a gate.*" - and how far did you get, where did you get stuck?

Comment: You forgot to share a **specific** question about that code

Comment: Following things are need to pass the test: 
- Return type should be a string.'

- calculateTotalBarLengthReq(500, 500, 20, ironBarThickness) should return "Total bar length requirement = 7021.59cm."

- calculateTotalBarLengthReq(100, 100, 20, ironBarThickness) should return "Total bar length requirement = 1308.32cm."

- The answer should be valid for any given input.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: @NicoHaase It is solved. Appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Please apply below logic and check

```js
function calculateTotalBarLengthReq(gateWidth, gateHeight, rowHeightPercentage, barThickness) {
  // Calculate the length of vertical bars (columns)
  const verticalBarLength = gateHeight * 2;

  // Calculate the size of each row
  const rowSize = gateHeight * rowHeightPercentage * 0.01;

  // Calculate the number of horizontal bars (rows)
  const numOfHorizontalBars = (gateHeight / rowSize) + 1;

  // Calculate the length of horizontal bars
  const horizontalBarLength = (gateWidth - barThickness * 2) * numOfHorizontalBars;

  // Calculate the gap between rows
  const rowGap = (gateHeight - numOfHorizontalBars * barThickness) / (numOfHorizontalBars - 1);

  // Calculate the number of circles in a row
  const numOfCirclesInRow = gateWidth / rowGap; //this may not natural number (float value)
  // const numOfCirclesInRow = Math.floor(gateWidth / rowGap); // this will give natural number (integer value)
  
  // Calculate the number of alternate rows with circles
  const numOfRowsWithCircles = Math.floor((numOfHorizontalBars - 1) / 2);

  // Calculate the total number of circles
  const totalNumOfCircles = numOfCirclesInRow * numOfRowsWithCircles;

  // Calculate the radius of each circle
  const radius = rowGap / 2;

  // Calculate the circumference of each circle
  const circumference = 2 * radius * Math.PI;

  // Calculate the total length of iron bars required
  const totalBarLength = verticalBarLength + horizontalBarLength + circumference * totalNumOfCircles;

  return `Total bar length requirement = ${totalBarLength.toFixed(2)}cm`;
}

const ironBarThickness = 10;
console.log(calculateTotalBarLengthReq(500, 500, 20, ironBarThickness));
console.log(calculateTotalBarLengthReq(100, 100, 20, ironBarThickness));
```

Note: From your example, when calculating to get desired output **7021.59**, number of circles in a row is not considered as a natural number (here it is 5.68). So, if you want to change the logic to take the number of circles in a row as natural number (that is 5) which gives output **6644.60**. Then, take the commented calculation of `numOfCirclesInRow`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Don't post answers that solely consist of code

Comment: @NicoHaase Certainly! I apologize for the previous response that consisted only of code. I have edited my answer with explanations.

Comment: Following things are need to pass the test: - Return type should be a string.' - calculateTotalBarLengthReq(500, 500, 20, ironBarThickness) should return "Total bar length requirement = 7021.59cm." - calculateTotalBarLengthReq(100, 100, 20, ironBarThickness) should return "Total bar length requirement = 1308.32cm." - The answer should be valid for any given input.

Comment: @RamodSasanga please see updated code with both examples.

Comment: @ZFLOCTECHNOLOGIES This code works well. Thank you very much!